# AVAYA Internal Loopback test failed during boot

Tags: loopback, avaya

Today, suddenly our network went down and I cannot get it up so far.
I noticed that our core switch was not functioning. I tried to reboot it but no luck.
Then I noticed that it can not pass a test during boot.
I couldn't find any proper document to understand issue on manufacturer's website and I'm not an advanced network expert. Switch is AVAYA VSP 7024XLS

is it a Stack issue or is there a loop in the network? (Nothing new joined to the network recently.)

Can anybody help me identify/diagnose the error messages?
Here are putty screenshots.

[image: avaya test fail]
[image: avaya test error log]

Comment: Please, _never_ use an image for text. Simply copy the text and paste it into your post using the Preformatted-text option (`{}`). It is likely you have a hardware problem, and you may need to replace the device.

Comment: I took screenshots during the first investigation of the incident and I didn't have live session in the putty by the time I created this question. I'll take note for the next time.

Comment: Your switch is broken. Get another one. (likely much cheaper than even attempting to fix it. there's not much inside there to fix, btw.)